Power Automate: how can I get the first n items from an array?
What function can I use to get the first n items of an array in Power Automate?
Context: In my Power Automate flow I have an action that outputs an array. In subsequent steps I use a For each action to iterate over each task in the array, but during development I don't want to iterate over hundreds of items during every test run. I want to use a Compose action to temporarily limit my main loop's input the first n items of the array.

Use take(), e.g. if n = 3:
take(YourArray, 3)

